# Include SQL Server PostDeployment from DB Project reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlproj, dbproj

We are splitting up one of our SQL Server DB Projects into two separate projects.

```
Core.DB
   Tables
   PostDeployment
   PreDeployment

Core.Seed (Reference to Core.DB)
   PostDeployment
   PreDeployment
```

I have the general "table" publish working but now I'm trying to figure out how to get the PostDeployment & PreDeployment scripts in the core folder to run.

Just to clarify.  When I publish from Core.Seed I want to have all the table publish (this is working) but I also need the Pre & Post Deployment scripts from both projects to run.

I can't figure out how to make this happen.   Any suggestions?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh (simple issue).

So this solution will work for you if you have your referenced project in the same solution.

In my PostDeployment.sql I have:

```
:r .\..\..\Core.DB\PostDeployment\_BasePostDeployment.sql
:r .\Client\_ClientPostDeployment.sql
```

Which allows me to reference the other project.